# How to implement an vertical range slider with interactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rangeslider, interact.js

I implemented a vertical range slider based on the interactjs example [here](https://interactjs.io/docs/)

The basic slider works well so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoagr40h/2/)

Now I want to add the slider to my website.

On the website, the slider is inside a grid-div with the classes *col-4* and *h-100*, so the div has a variable height and width.

```
 <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between container-zoom-one" style="border:1px solid #ADADAD; border-radius: 0.25rem;">
                   
      <div class="slider-categorie"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></div>
      <div class="slider-frame">
           <div class="slider"></div>
      </div>
      <output class="slider-output">0</output>
 
 </div>
```

I also have a div above and below the slider to show the category and the value of the slider. I tried to give these divs a fixed height and the slider should use the full space.

My website looks someting like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d2ae6y8v/)

By moving the thumb up to 100, you can see weird behavior. On my website, the behavior is even weirder. I can't get the thumb up to 100 and the div's height (js variable *sliderHeight*) is getting bigger and bigger.

[image]
[image]